# How did Python read this binary faster the second time?

Tags: python, io, python-internals

I'm exploring methods for reading a formatted binary file and was starting with the basics:

```
>>> with open(fp, 'rb') as f:
        buffer = f.read()
```

My file is 1.02GB and it took ~90 seconds to read it and store in memory the first time. By chance I accidentally told the interpreter to read the file again (hit Enter too many times) and it read it in 0.5 seconds. The file was closed prior to re-reading unintentionally.

Whats going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the file data was cached and still in memory. Most operating systems will leave data in memory for a while, in case it is asked for again.

Comment: I was not aware of that since I dumped the content too, interesting.

Comment: I think from Python's point of view the data is gone, but the OS keeps it hanging around just in case. If the OS runs out of free space in memory, and you have not run your program for say 1 hour, then probably it will decide to really delete your data.

Comment: Makes sense. I repeated the process a few minutes ago and it took the former time.

Comment: Research "Garbage Collector" which will tell you more. Probably in earlier languages/systems, if a program said to delete the data, it would happen straight away.

Answer (score 1):

The second time your file was cached in memory. This has nothing to do with Python.